# tar command can't find file or directory

Tags: command-line, tar

I'm new user of Ubuntu 12.04, and I don't know what should I do.
I had download tor-browser and in instruction it said I should use this command for extracting tar file:

```
tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux64-3.5.3_en-US.tar .xz
```

but it give me this:

```
tar (child): tor-browser-linux64-3.5.3_en-US.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

but that file exist because I use `ls` command as below:

```
ls Downloads
tor-browser-linux64-3.5.3_en-US.tar.xz
```

I also use:

```
cd Downloads
```

but it didn't work to, where I did it wrong?

Comment: it's work thank you drag and drop was wonderful way, thank you so much.

Comment: @user264363 You did wrong because you put a space in the file's name: `.tar .xz`. If there is really a space, then you should escape it: `.tar\ .xz` or put the file name between quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to the folder where the file is to extract it.
The Downloads folder is in your home folder. 
Your home folder is in `/home/yourusername`, but you can access to it with `~`. 
Try:

```
cd ~/Downloads

ls
```

if your file is really there, then execute the tar command

```
tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux64-3.5.3_en-US.tar.xz
```

Or if you don't feel confident with the console, you can open a file manager, go to the location of your file, right click on it and select "extract here". This will do the same thing as your command.

If you want to avoid typos when using the terminal, you can:

- Type  tar -xvJf, and drag the file onto the terminal window. (Thanks [Jacob2](https://askubuntu.com/users/72216/jacob))
- Start typing the name of the file name and press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. This will complete the name of the file if only one file starts with the string that you have typed. If there are more files starting with that name, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again and you will see a list of options.